# R shiny datatable costumize column filter width

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have an R shiny app with different tables.
One of my tables has a column with many values ranging from 1 to a big number, around 50,000.
Since the table has many columns it's quite impossible to use the column filter available from the code below.
If you run the code and click in the white space below the column name, you will see the filter.
If you try to move the filter cursor a little bit for example to exclude rows with values less than 5, you will notice that a very microscopic move of the filter will jump from 0 to 200, making the filter quite useless.
My question is: can we customize the width of the filter to be as large as the table? This would probably allow to use more efficiently use the filter.

```
df = mtcars
for(i in 1:1000) df = rbind(df, mtcars)
rownames(df) = NULL
df$CUSTOM_COLUMN = as.numeric(rownames(df))
datatable(df, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE), filter = list(position = 'top'))
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It's literally within the question above. Notice how you do not need a shiny app to replicate the problem. This is a datatable type of question so you could simply replicate without shiny.

Comment: your code wont run like this since the syntax is wrog, also rendering DT inside shiny runtime will lead to a different output than running in RStudio. so to replicate you problem it would be ideal to give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I completely disagree. If you run the code above in R studio you will get exactly what you get in the Shiny app. There's nothing wrong with the syntax so please don't make things up.

Comment: ok i didnt know you could do a for loop without '{}' however there is no slider as shown in your picture